# Sending variable from a PHP file to another PHp file

Tags: php

I have a php file called "Users.php". In this file I have written a program that shows all faculties general information. But  for the user id I have created a link, that when users click on it, they will be directed to another page which shows more information for that faculty.

```
<td><a href="usersdetails.php?users=$row['userid']"><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></a></td>
```

And in another PHP file called "usersdetail.php". I am using $_GET to receive userid. like this:

```
$id= $_GET["users"];
```

but when I use

```
 echo $id;
```

what I see is : `$row['userid']`

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: As a side note, be careful using only the I'd of the object you wish to interact with in the URL. Presumably this app will grow and require restricted data between users (not uncommon). At which point you'll then need to integrate some sort of check to make sure the user has a right to access that URL. My advice is to pass a session id and check the referrer.

Comment: Actually I just found the answer. In case some one has the same problem:<td><a href="usersdetails.php?users=<?php echo $row['userid']?>"><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></a></td>

Answer (score 2):

do

```
<td><a href="usersdetails.php?users=<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></a></td>
```

instead of

```
<td><a href="usersdetails.php?users=*$row['userid']*"><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must interpret all your variables using PHP. Your variable inside the href attribute is not between the `<?php ?>` tags.

Use this instead

```
<td><a href="usersdetails.php?users=<?php echo $row['userid'] ?>"><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></a></td>
```

This will interpret both variables in PHP and will output the correct value.